# Haskell: Read a binary file backwards

Tags: file, haskell, binary, reverse

I'm looking to find the last 32bit word in an uInt32 binary dump matching a particular pattern using Haskell. I am able to complete the task using `last`, however the code must trawl through the entire file so it is rather inefficient.

Is there a simple way to make `readfile` operate through the file in reverse? I believe this would solve the issue with the smallest change to the current code.

Here is my current code, for reference. I only began with Haskell this weekend so I am sure it is quite ugly. It looks for the last 32 bit word beginning with 0b10 at the MSB.

```
import System.Environment(getArgs)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal as BL
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import Data.Binary.Get
import Data.Word
import Data.Bits
import Text.Printf(printf)

main = do
  args <- getArgs
  let file = args!!0
  putStrLn $ "Find last 0xCXXXXXXX in " ++ file

  content <- BL.readFile file

  let packets = getPackets content
  putStrLn . show . getValue . last . filterTimes $ packets

-- Data

type Packet = Word32

-- filter where first 2 bits are 10
filterTimes :: [Packet] -> [Packet]
filterTimes = filter ((== 0x2) . tag)

-- get the first 2 bits
tag :: Packet -> Packet
tag rp =
  let tagSize = 2
  in  shiftR rp (finiteBitSize rp - tagSize)

-- remove the tag bits
getValue :: Packet -> Packet
getValue =
  let tagSize = 2
      mask    = complement $ rotateR (2^tagSize - 1) tagSize
  in (.&.) mask

-- Input
-- Based on https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary/docs/Data-Binary-Get.html

getPacket :: Get Packet
getPacket = do
  packet <- getWord32le
  return $! packet

getPackets :: BL.ByteString -> [Packet]
getPackets input0 = go decoder input0
  where
    decoder = runGetIncremental getPacket
    go :: Decoder Packet -> BL.ByteString -> [Packet]
    go (Done leftover _consumed packet) input =
      packet : go decoder (BL.chunk leftover input)
    go (Partial k) input                     =
      go (k . takeHeadChunk $ input) (dropHeadChunk input)
    go (Fail _leftover _consumed msg) _input =
      []

takeHeadChunk :: BL.ByteString -> Maybe BS.ByteString
takeHeadChunk lbs =
  case lbs of
    (BL.Chunk bs _) -> Just bs
    _ -> Nothing

dropHeadChunk :: BL.ByteString -> BL.ByteString
dropHeadChunk lbs =
  case lbs of
    (BL.Chunk _ lbs') -> lbs'
    _ -> BL.Empty
```

Comment: Well, you could use the `Handle` with `hSeek`, jump repeatedly back from the end of the file and read the file in chunks. Getting those chunks right will be the hard part.

Comment: In terms of efficiency, there is no difference in expected run time for all possible inputs; a function as proposed by @Zeta would probably be slower for inputs that have their last matched word fairly at the beginning. If you have no other knowledge over the input, your approach seems fine. Other than that, you could use seeking backwards. But this might cause problems depending on the hard drive (as consecutive reading is faster because there is no seeking needed for the hard drive.)

Comment: This would not be as small a change as you're looking for, but consider using the [MMap package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmap-0.5.9/docs/System-IO-MMap.html) to only load the part of the file you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments on your code:

1. You are using `last` which could throw an exception. You should use `lastMay` fromthe [**safe**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe) package which returns a Maybe.
2. Since you are just treating the file as a vector of Word32s, I don't think it's worth using Data.Binary.Get and the associated overhead and complexity that it entails. Just treat the file as a (perhaps lazy) ByteString and access every 4th byte or break it up into 4-byte substrings.

You can have a look at code which uses ByteStrings [here](https://github.com/erantapaa/read-word32). It implements the following approaches to the problem:

- Read in the entire file as a lazy ByteString and produce a (lazy) list of 4-byte substrings. Return the last substring which satisifies the criteria.

  ```
  intoWords :: BL.ByteString -> [ BL.ByteString ]
  intoWords bs
    | BL.null a = []
    | otherwise = a : intoWords b
    where (a,b) = BL.splitAt 4 bs

  -- find by breaking the file into 4-byte words
  find_C0_v1 :: FilePath -> IO (Maybe BL.ByteString)
  find_C0_v1 path = do
    contents <- BL.readFile path
    return $ lastMay . filter (\bs -> BL.index bs 0 == 0xC0) . intoWords $ contents
  ```
- Read in the entire file as a lazy ByteString and access every 4-th byte looking for a 0xC0. Return the last occurrence.

  ```
  -- find by looking at every 4th byte
  find_C0_v2 :: FilePath -> IO (Maybe BL.ByteString)
  find_C0_v2 path = do
    contents <- BL.readFile path
    size <- fmap fromIntegral $ withFile path ReadMode hFileSize
    let wordAt i = BL.take 4 . BL.drop i $ contents
    return $ fmap wordAt $ lastMay $ filter (\i -> BL.index contents i == 0xC0) [0,4..size-1]
  ```
- Read the file in backwards in chunks of 64K. Within each chunk (which is a strict ByteString) access every 4th byte looking for a 0xC0 starting from the end of the chunk. Return the first occurrence.

  ```
  -- read a file backwords until a predicate returns a Just value
  loopBlocks :: Int -> Handle -> Integer -> (BS.ByteString -> Integer -> Maybe a) -> IO (Maybe a)
  loopBlocks blksize h top pred
    | top <= 0 = return Nothing
    | otherwise   = do
          let offset = top - fromIntegral blksize
          hSeek h AbsoluteSeek offset
          blk <- BS.hGet h blksize
          case pred blk offset of
            Nothing -> loopBlocks blksize h offset pred
            x       -> return x

  -- find by reading backwords lookint at every 4th byte
  find_C0_v3 :: FilePath -> IO (Maybe Integer)
  find_C0_v3 path = do
    withFile path ReadMode $ \h -> do
      size <- hFileSize h
      let top = size - (mod size 4)
          blksize = 64*1024 :: Int
      loopBlocks blksize h top $ \blk offset ->
            fmap ( (+offset) . fromIntegral ) $ headMay $ filter (\i -> BS.index blk i == 0xC0) [blksize-4,blksize-8..0]
  ```

The third method is the fastest even if it has to read in the entire file. The first method actually works pretty well. I wouldn't recommend the second at all - its performance degrades precipitously as the file size grows.

Comment: Thanks. I really like solution 3 here: seeking through data chunks which can be reversed. It is flexible enough to still be used within the framework I have.

Comment: Very comprehensive answer too, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

For any others who may be interested, I have adapted @ErikR's answer. This solution follows his proposed solution 3, but makes use of my existing code, by stepping through blocks in reverse lazily.

This requires a few extra imports:

```
import System.IO
import Safe
import Data.Maybe
```

`main` becomes:

```
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  let file = args!!0
  putStrLn $ "Find last 0xCXXXXXXX in " ++ file

  -- forward
  withFile file ReadMode $ \h -> do
    content <- BL.hGetContents h
    let packets = getPackets content
    putStrLn . show . getValue . last . filterTimes $ packets

  -- reverse
  withFile file ReadMode $ \h -> do
    size <- hFileSize h
    let blksize = 64*1024 :: Int
    chunks <- makeReverseChunks blksize h (fromIntegral size)
    putStrLn . show . getValue . (fromMaybe 0) . headMay . catMaybes . (map $ lastMay . filterTimes . getPackets) $ chunks
```

With an added helper function:

```
-- create list of data chunks, backwards in order through the file
makeReverseChunks :: Int -> Handle -> Int -> IO [BL.ByteString]
makeReverseChunks blksize h top
  | top == 0 = return []
  | top < 0  = error "negative file index"
  | otherwise   = do
        let offset = max (top - fromIntegral blksize) 0
        hSeek h AbsoluteSeek (fromIntegral offset)
        blk <- BL.hGet h blksize
        rest <- makeReverseChunks blksize h offset
        return $ blk : rest
```

Comment: The function `makeReverseChunks` is currently quite strict. The use of lazy bytestrings is not helping. In order to achieve lazy reading one must use `unsafeInterleaveIO`. Here is a solution using strict bytestrings, lazy IO, and tail recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation of the function `makeReverseChunks`. It was currently quite strict. Moreover the use of lazy bytestrings is not helping if one keep the blksize low enough. In order to achieve lazy reading one must use `unsafeInterleaveIO`. Here is a solution using strict bytestrings and lazy IO:

```
-- create list of data chunks, backwards in order through the file
makeReverseChunks :: Int -> Handle -> Int -> IO [SBS.ByteString]
makeReverseChunks blksize h top
  | top == 0 = return []
  | top < 0  = error "negative file index"
  | otherwise   = do
    let offset = max (top - fromIntegral blksize) 0
    hSeek h AbsoluteSeek (fromIntegral offset)
    blk <- SBS.hGet h blksize
    rest <- unsafeInterleaveIO $ makeReverseChunks blksize h offset
    return $ blk : rest
```